# Microsoft IIS6.0 and Windows 2003

Tags: iis

I was doing a vulnerability test. I have connected to the IP:Port 
and Server response banner of IIS/6.0. For IIS/6.0 does it implies that windows server is 2003,this is because 2003 I supposed is end of life already/

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6 can be either Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP Professional x64 Edition

Full matrix can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)

Yes Windows Server 2003 extended support ended on [July 14, 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/cloud-platform/windows-server-2003).
This means you will not have any support nor update anymore (even security or critical updates).
Furthermore their security technologies are outdated.

Thus both operating systems are considered as critical security holes by every serious security scanner.